# Create a label/value (readonly) fieldset using zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I just want to create a Label/value row like this:

```
<label>
    <span>My Label:</span><span>My value from my object</span>
</label>
```

So what should I put in the **type** attribute ?

```
$this->add(array (
    'name' => 'myFieldName',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type' => '???????',
    ),
    'options' => array (
        'label' => 'My Label:',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->add(array (
    'name' => 'myFieldName',
    'type' => 'hidden',
    'options' => array (
        'label' => 'My Label:',
    ),
));
```

And in view

```
<?php $element = $form->get('myFieldName') ?>
<label>
    <span><?php echo $element->getLabel() ?></span>
    <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($element->getValue()) ?></span>
</label>
```